# Does static electricity dissipate if object is sealed in insulator sphere?

Tags: electrical-engineering, electrical

I rub a piece of glass against some silk. Normally, left in open air, it would lose its acquired charge. What will happen if after rubbing, I immediately seal it inside a sphere made of insulator material (kind of like a "Faraday cage", but not metal)? Will the glass piece stay charged forever? Assume that no air enters/exits the sphere after putting the glass piece inside.

Since the moisture in the air would only neutralize so much charge per unit volume of air, I think the glass should keep the remaining charge pretty much forever. The walls of the sphere can't dissipate it either as they don't conduct. And unless electric breakdown happens, there is no way the charge is neutralizing through the walls?

Comment: Better asked on the Physics Stack

Comment: The charge will dissipate, just very slowly. The glass sphere forms a capacitor, with the air on the inside and outside as conductors, and the sphere itself as insulator. The sphere is presumably thick enough that the capacitance will be very low, but it can slowly dissipate nonetheless.

Comment: Flash memory traps charges for years.

Comment: You don't need electric breakdown for charges to move. Insulators aren't perfect hence leakage currents.

Comment: @AJN what's the secret? Is it the geometry, materials, strength of the field or what?

Comment: @DKNguyen Well I should expect a stable charge (and thus field) for one day, no?

Comment: Define "stable".

Comment: @DKNguyen That I won't lose more than 5% of the initial charge.

Comment: Seems plausible though I've never actually measured.